# Is there a phrase sounds like "fulls rise" to describe a job well done?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=250) (a video link with a time stamp)

> closing
>   the door and that's going to create
>   steam which is going to help my bread
>   doughs ... my braed ball bowls **hoes and right**
>   and get a nice beautiful round shape ...

there is a phrase in her saying sounds like "fulls rise".

Is there a phrase sounds like "fulls rise" to describe a job well done?

Comment: "bread bowls **arise** and get" or perhaps "bread bowls [uh] **rise** and get."

Comment: @user105719 Thank you! With your help, I heard a clear "rise". It seems that the one between "bread bowl" and "rise" is mystery.

Comment: You're listening to likely-unscripted, informal speech -- it's full of rephrasings, backtracking, vocal hesitations, and the like. Are you learning English from the video or are you just fascinated with bread bowls? If it's the former, that's the hard way to do it.

Comment: @user105719 Unfortunately, It's the former. I've tried a few courses, almost all of which are aimed for written english or non-actually-everyday spoken english. So, I am trying food videos.